# Finding sequence in data and grouping by it

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

Data in Phone_number column of my Temp_table looks like this

```
1234560200
1234560201
1234560202
2264540300
2264540301
2264540302
2264540303
2264540304
2264540305
2264540306
```

I want it to find sequence of last 4 digits and and find First and Last number of sequence of it. For eg.
There is sequence of first 3 rows as `0200, 0201, 0202, so First = 0200 and Last = 0202`

Final Output of this query should be

```
First  Last

0200   0202
0300   0306
```

I tried below query, but not sure about this approach.

```
WITH get_nxt_range AS 
(
  select substr(a.PHONE_NUMBER,7,4) range1, 
  LEAD(substr(a.PHONE_NUMBER,7,4)) OVER (ORDER BY a.PHONE_NUMBER ) nxt_range
  from Temp_table a
)
SELECT range1,nxt_range FROM get_nxt_range
WHERE nxt_range = range1 +1
ORDER BY range1
```

Comment: What are you not sure about? What happened with the query you tried - does that query get the result you expect? Does it error? And, are you looking for ranges within that - what would expect if 2264540303 wasn't there for example?

Comment: It doesnt give me error, But then I have applied Connect by Prior clause to this query, and Server Died

Comment: Do you always have same prefixes for adjacent last four digits?

Comment: Yes, the format is going to be the same

Comment: Is it possible to have "holes" for the same prefix (e.g. 123456)?

Comment: Its a Phone number, prefix can be anything, We must focus on last 4 digits i.e. Min of last four digit be 0000 and max be 9999, without grouping

Comment: I mean following: 
1234560201
1234560203
1234560204 - are there two intervals or still one?

Comment: These are Two instacnes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103957/discussion-between-rudolf-yurgenson-and-rohansr002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
select
  min (substr (phone_number, -4, 4)) as first,
  max (substr (phone_number, -4, 4)) as last
from temp_table
group by
  substr (phone_number, -4, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best solution I got :)

Answer (score 2):

One method to get sequences is to use the difference of row numbers approach.  This works in your case as well:

```
select substr(phone_number, 1, 6),
       min(substr(phone_number, 7, 4)), max(substr(phone_number, 7, 4))
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by phone_number) -
              row_number() over (partition by substr(phone_number, 1, 6) order by phone_number)
             ) as grp
      from temp_table t
     ) t
group by substr(phone_number, 1, 6), grp;
```

Comment: `phone_number(7, 4)` or `SubStr(phone_number, 7, 4)`??

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       COALESCE(
         first_in_sequence,
         LAG( first_in_sequence ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY phone_number )
       ) AS first_in_sequence,
       COALESCE(
         last_in_sequence,
         LAG( last_in_sequence ) IGNORE NULLS OVER ( ORDER BY phone_number )
       ) AS last_in_sequence
FROM   (
  SELECT phone_number,
         CASE phone_number
           WHEN LAG( phone_number ) OVER ( ORDER BY phone_number ) + 1
           THEN NULL
           ELSE phone_number
           END AS first_in_sequence,
         CASE phone_number
           WHEN LEAD( phone_number ) OVER ( ORDER BY phone_number ) - 1
           THEN NULL
           ELSE phone_number
           END AS last_in_sequence
  FROM   temp_table
);
```

**Update**:

```
CREATE TABLE phone_numbers ( phone_number ) AS
select 1234560200 from dual union all
select 1234560201 from dual union all
select 1234560202 from dual union all
select 2264540300 from dual union all
select 2264540301 from dual union all
select 2264540302 from dual union all
select 2264540303 from dual union all
select 2264540304 from dual union all
select 2264540305 from dual union all
select 2264540306 from dual;

SELECT MIN( phone_number ) AS first_in_sequence,
       MAX( phone_number ) AS last_in_sequence
FROM   (
  SELECT phone_number,
         phone_number - ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY phone_number ) AS grp
  FROM   phone_numbers
)
GROUP BY grp;
```

**Output**:

```
FIRST_IN_SEQUENCE LAST_IN_SEQUENCE
----------------- ----------------
       2264540300   2264540306
       1234560200   1234560202
```

Comment: Dude, this is a huge table, and have to use this query in select statement

Comment: @rohansr002 - Ok, it is a huge table, but that does not tell me anything as to why you think this is a problem.

Comment: @rohansr002 Added a second solution that will give the same result.

Comment: Second solution is superb

Answer (score 0):

If 1234560201 1234560203 1234560204 are two instances then this should work:

```
with tt as (
  select substr(PHONE_NUMBER,7,4) id from Temp_table
), 
t as (
  select 
    t1.id, 
    case when t3.id is null then 1 else 0 end start, 
    case when t2.id is null then 1 else 0 end "end" 
  from tt t1
  -- no next adjacent element - we have an end of interval
  left outer join tt t2 on t2.id - 1 = t1.id
  -- not previous adjacent element - we have a start of interval
  left outer join tt t3 on t3.id + 1 = t1.id
  -- select starts and ends only
  where t2.id is null or t3.id is null
)
-- find nearest end record for each start record (it may be the same record)
select t1.id, (select min(id) from t where id >= t1.id and "end" = 1)
from t t1
where t1.start = 1
```

Comment: Dude, this is a huge table, and have to use this query in select statement

Comment: What do you mean by 'use this query in select statement'? You can't use any query in select statement other than one that returns single value.

Answer (score 0):

I see guys already have answered for your question.
I just want to propose my variant how resolve this task:

```
with list_num (phone_number) as (
    select 1234560200 from dual union all
    select 1234560201 from dual union all
    select 1234560202 from dual union all
    select 2264540300 from dual union all
    select 2264540301 from dual union all
    select 2264540302 from dual union all
    select 2264540303 from dual union all
    select 2264540304 from dual union all
    select 2264540305 from dual union all
    select 2264540306 from dual)

select root as from_value,
       max(phone_number) keep (dense_rank last order by lvl) as to_value
from 
  (select phone_number, level as lvl, CONNECT_BY_ROOT phone_number as root
   from 
      (select phone_number,
              decode(phone_number-lag (phone_number) over(order by phone_number),1,1,0) as start_value
       from list_num) b
   connect by nocycle phone_number = prior phone_number + 1
   start with start_value = 0)
group by root
having count(1) > 1
```

If you need only last 4 numbers just *substr* it.

```
substr(root,7,4) as from_value,
substr(max(phone_number) keep (dense_rank last order by lvl),7,4) as to_value
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dude, this is a huge table, and have to use this query in select statement